# SQL Order Alphanumeric String of fixed length first by alpha-chars and then by numeric-values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I order the following data by alpha characters before ordering by numeric values in SQL Server?

'00141W703','001413541','00141B204','00141A586','00900W738','0075W0825','001C5A389'

Expected Results

```
'001C5A389'
'00141A586'
'00141B204'
'00141W703'
'001413541'
'0075W0825'
'00900W738'
```

All the similar questions asked here previously are for specific string patterns wherein the data to be sorted/ordered are either starting with alpha-chars/numeric-values. But in this case the string to be ordered are of fixed length but the position of alpha-chars and numeric-values are completely random. It's almost as if they sort each character from left to right with alpha-chars ordered first ascending and then followed by numeric-values in the ascending order.

A sample data set given below:

```
CREATE TABLE tab
    (col varchar(9));
    
INSERT INTO tab
    (col)
VALUES
    ('00141W703'),
    ('001413541'),
    ('00141B204'),
    ('00141A586'),
    ('00900W738'),
    ('0075W0825'),
    ('001C5A389');
```

I appreciate the solutions provided are tested on fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/qHEWHO4F

Comment: @DaleK - Sorry there was an incorrect test data. I have made the updates. Like I said the ordering should be done left to right for each positions. So ideally for each position the ordering should be A-Z first and then 0-9. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Now if I read from left to right each positions, first 3 are numbers in this example, so I can easily say '001' is the lowest. But when I move to the fourth character I have a '4' and 'C' in the data set. So according to the expected result, 'C' would be given precedence over the lowest numerical character

Comment: @DaleK -  I have already tried these solutions (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/842541/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-Server-to-Sort-Alphanumeric-Value) for alphanumeric strings but they don't help my use-case

Comment: Why isn't  001413541 since it has no letters?

Comment: @DaleK -  Thank you so much for your solution. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. May I ask a naive question as to what does 'z' or '9' imply on those case statements in your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very crude, brute force method, there is bound to be a better solution out there.

Essentially you sort by each column, first if its an alpha character, then a second time if its a numeric character.

Using "z" and "9" to ensure nulls come last.

```
select *
from tab
order by
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,1,1)) = 0 then substring(col,1,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,1,1)) = 1 then substring(col,1,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,2,1)) = 0 then substring(col,2,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,2,1)) = 1 then substring(col,2,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,3,1)) = 0 then substring(col,3,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,3,1)) = 1 then substring(col,3,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,4,1)) = 0 then substring(col,4,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,4,1)) = 1 then substring(col,4,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,5,1)) = 0 then substring(col,5,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,5,1)) = 1 then substring(col,5,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,6,1)) = 0 then substring(col,6,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,6,1)) = 1 then substring(col,6,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,7,1)) = 0 then substring(col,7,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,7,1)) = 1 then substring(col,7,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,8,1)) = 0 then substring(col,8,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,8,1)) = 1 then substring(col,8,1) else '9' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,9,1)) = 0 then substring(col,9,1) else 'z' end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,9,1)) = 1 then substring(col,9,1) else '9' end asc;
```

Actually this way is a bit neater... add 75 to the ASCII values for the numbers to give them higher ASCII values than the alpha-characters.

```
select *
from tab
order by
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,1,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,1,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,1,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,2,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,2,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,2,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,3,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,3,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,3,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,4,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,4,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,4,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,5,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,5,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,5,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,6,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,6,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,6,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,7,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,7,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,7,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,8,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,8,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,8,1)) + 75 end asc,
    case when isnumeric(substring(col,9,1)) = 0 then ascii(substring(col,9,1))
    else ascii(substring(col,9,1)) + 75 end asc;
```

And a touch neater again:

```
with cte as (
    select *
        , ascii(substring(col,1,1)) order1
        , ascii(substring(col,2,1)) order2
        , ascii(substring(col,3,1)) order3
        , ascii(substring(col,4,1)) order4
        , ascii(substring(col,5,1)) order5
        , ascii(substring(col,6,1)) order6
        , ascii(substring(col,7,1)) order7
        , ascii(substring(col,8,1)) order8
        , ascii(substring(col,9,1)) order9
    from tab
)
select col
from cte
order by
    case when order1 < 65 then order1 + 75 else order1 end asc,
    case when order2 < 65 then order2 + 75 else order2 end asc,
    case when order3 < 65 then order3 + 75 else order3 end asc,
    case when order4 < 65 then order4 + 75 else order4 end asc,
    case when order5 < 65 then order5 + 75 else order5 end asc,
    case when order6 < 65 then order6 + 75 else order6 end asc,
    case when order7 < 65 then order7 + 75 else order7 end asc,
    case when order8 < 65 then order8 + 75 else order8 end asc,
    case when order9 < 65 then order9 + 75 else order9 end asc;
```

Comment: Yes this is way more neater and easier to interpret. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Even neater now.